# Browser returns Json to be redefined as a specific object

Tags: php, json, casting

This is the scenario I have,

I am using PHP and Jquery.

An object is encoded as Json and sent to a browser, the user then makes changes to the data and updates, the self same Json string that has been passed is now being returned to the class to be decoded.

How can I ensure that when I decode the Json string, I can re-create the object with the new data defined from the new Json String.

Would I have to re-initialise passing the data to be re-defined in a new object or is there a way for this to be picked up automatically?

Comment: Please, read the help center of this site, specifically [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have 2 answers, focusing on 2 completely different things (JS <=> PHP), so your question could be more specific. You haven't shown us any efforts on your part, nor any specific problems you're facing. After looking at my answer, I'm inclined to say that I've put more effort into answering your question than you have in researching/trying to solve this problem yourself... I've written more code than you've shown here, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically? No, there is no way of mapping JSON strings to constructors. You *could* write your own function, though, or do some checks in your object's constructor:

```
function jsonToClass($string, $class)
{
    $className = $class;
    if (is_object($class)) $className = get_class($class);
    return new $className(json_decode($string));
}
```

Then, in your object's constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $prop1 = null;
    public $prop2 = null;
    private $set = array('prop2', 'prop1');

    public function __construct(stdClass $json)
    {
        foreach($json as $prop => $val)
        {//set properties
             if (in_array($prop, $this->set)) $this->{$prop} = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

To easily json-ify your object, you could even go as far as implement a `__toString` magic method, or a method that you have to call manually:

```
public function __toString()
{
    $return = array();
    foreach($this->set as $prop)
    {
        $return[$prop] = $this->{$prop};
    }
    //optionally - probably a bad idea, though
    $return['class'] = __CLASS__;
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

And then, when sending an instance of this class, simply do:

```
return (string) $instance;
```

BTW, a method you'd call manually will look pretty similar but is probably preferable:

```
//define format constants
const FORMAT_ARRAY = 1;
const FORMAT_OBJ = 2;
const FROMAT_JSON = 3;
//some specials
const FORMAT_OBJ_REC = 4;//recursive object

public function format($format = self::FORMAT_ARRAY, array $exclude = array())
{
    $return = array();
    foreach($this->set as $prop)
    {
        if (!in_array($prop, $exclude) $return[$prop] = $this->{$prop};
    }
    //optionally - probably a bad idea, though
    if (!in_array('class', $exclude)) $return['class'] = __CLASS__;
    switch($format)
    {
        case self::FORMAT_ARRAY: return $return;
        case self::FORMAT_OBJ: return (object) $return;
        case self::FORMAT_OBJ_REC: return json_decode(json_encode($return));
        case self::FORMAT_JSON: return json_encode($return);
    }
}
```

And so on.

*Notes*
The reason why I wouldn't return the class in a JSON string is simply because that's server-side information, the client/front-end has no business knowing what class was sent over, so don't send it.
The reason for the `FORMAT_OBJ_REC` is simply because a cast to object only casts the array, it doesn't cast recursively:

```
$foo = (object) array('foo' => array('bar' => 'foobar'));
var_dump($foo->foo);
```

dumps an array, whereas:

```
$foo = json_decode(json_encode(array('foo'=>array('bar'=> 'foobar'))));
var_dump($foo->foo);
```

will dump an instance of `stdClass`

Lastly, if you're thinking of implementing this `format` method (after working on it a bit more), might I suggest creating an `interface`, `trait` or `abstract class` to implement this? Something along the lines of:

```
interface Formatable
{//horrid name, I know
    const FORMAT_ARRAY = 1;
    const FORMAT_OBJ = 2;
    const FROMAT_JSON = 3;
    const FORMAT_OBJ_REC = 4;

    public function format($format = self::FORMAT_ARRAY, array $exclude = array());
}
//implement for data classes
abstract class DataModels implements Formatable
{
    protected $properties = array();
    public $something = null;
    final public function format($format = self::FORMAT_ARRAY, array $exclude = array())
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach($this->set as $prop)
        {
            if (!in_array($prop, $exclude))
            {//format recursively through type-hinting!
                $return[$prop] = $this->{$prop} instanceof Formatable ?
                     $this->{$prop}->format($format, $exclude) : $this->{$prop}
            }
        }
        if (!in_array('class', $exclude)) $return['class'] = __CLASS__;
        switch($format)
        {
            case self::FORMAT_ARRAY: return $return;
            case self::FORMAT_OBJ: return (object) $return;
            case self::FORMAT_OBJ_REC: return json_decode(json_encode($return));
            case self::FORMAT_JSON: return json_encode($return);
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException($format. ' is not a valid format type');
        }
    }
}
```

***Warning***
None of this code is tested, I've just written it here off the top of my head, it may well contain errors.